# Is it invalid to use a MySQL function several times in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was writing a query to get the popular posts based on the comments, and trying to show the total number of comments for every single post. There is two tables named posts and comments; post_id is a field of comments table and also the foreign key which is connected to posts' table primary id. This query is working well with PHP code, but being for new in coding I'm not sure whether my written query format is technically right as I have used **COUNT()**  SQL function several times within a single query. Looking for expert opinion and advice. Thanks!

`$sql = "SELECT posts.id AS p_id, posts.datetime, title, image, 
-> COUNT(posts.id) AS cnt, COUNT(comments.comment) AS tcom FROM 
-> posts JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id AND status='ON' 
-> GROUP BY posts.id, post_id ORDER BY cnt DESC";`